# "invalid-request-cookie" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, recaptcha

So for some reason I'm getting a "invalid-request-cookie" when trying to submit a ReCaptcha. I'm using the [ReCaptcha gem](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/).

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I have my ReCaptcha public and private keys in my bash_profile so that shouldn't be an issue.

**UsersStepsController.rb**

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController

  def show
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user 
    captcha_message = "The data you entered for the CAPTCHA wasn't correct.  Please try again"
    if !verify_recaptcha(message: captcha_message)
      render :add_recaptcha
      else
       redirect_to root_path and return
    end
  end

  def add_recaptcha 
    @user = current_user
  end

end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
  patch '/user_steps', to: 'user_steps#update', as: 'update_user_steps'
  resources :user_steps, except: [:update]
  get '/add_recaptcha', to: 'user_steps#add_recaptcha'
```

**user_steps/add_captcha.html.erb**

```
<fieldset class="clearfix">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeUQ_xxxx_etc"></div>
  <div align="center"><%= recaptcha_tags :public_key => ENV['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY'] %></div>
  <%= form_for(@user, {url: update_user_steps_path(id: @user.to_param)}) do |f| %>
  <br> 
  <%= f.submit "Done", class: "styling" %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

**Update Logs:**

```
Started PATCH "/user_steps?id=35" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-26 11:55:52 -0500
Started PATCH "/user_steps?id=35" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-26 11:55:52 -0500
Processing by UserStepsController#update as HTML
Processing by UserStepsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sEOPI8KVuXLPSLjXVajF8QcWeLcUpibgHq6hHqgtwGA=", "commit"=>"Done", "id"=>"35"}
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sEOPI8KVuXLPSLjXVajF8QcWeLcUpibgHq6hHqgtwGA=", "commit"=>"Done", "id"=>"35"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 35  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 35  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/headers/_header_sign_up_step2.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/headers/_header_sign_up_step2.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered user_steps/add_recaptcha.html.erb within layouts/application (28.2ms)
  Rendered user_steps/add_recaptcha.html.erb within layouts/application (28.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 919ms (Views: 800.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 919ms (Views: 800.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Comment: Please post the backtrace for the error.

Comment: Sure! Updated the original post.

Comment: Could it be that the captcha challenges that are being submitted are being encrypted? And how can we prevent this from happening?

Comment: So the logs you posted don't contain a backtrace of the error. I'm assuming you're seeing "invalid-request-cookie" error in your server logs... where is that error being logged?

Comment: Here's the thing, there's no actual backtrace because the error is a prompt on the website in the form of a flash[:error], rather than a full blown error page. The error prompt is related to the ReCaptcha gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer :) You need to include that inside your form unless the value won't be saved!

```
<fieldset class="clearfix">
  <%= form_for(@user, {url: update_user_steps_path(id: @user.to_param)}) do |f| %>
    <div align="center"><%= recaptcha_tags :public_key => ENV['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY'] %></div>
  <br> 
  <%= f.submit "Done", class: "styling" %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```